# How can I work with multi level dictionnary?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following json data to work with:

```json
"result": {
  "json": {
    "licences": {
      "4216": {
        "license": "4512-5421-5134-7413"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I first tried to get my expected value with the following debug task:

```yaml
- name: Display Licence ID
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: result.json.licences[0].license
```

But it returns :

```
"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

As a work-around I'm currently using :

```yaml
- name: Display Licence ID
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: result.json.licences[result.json.licences|first].license
```

This works but isn't there a better way than repeating the whole variable name?

Comment: Your file json is not correct

Comment: @Frenchy comment is totally right. Since you gave a working scenario, I took for granted this was only a copy/paste error and fixed the data in your question. Please check my fix is aligned with your actual data and edit with a correction otherwise. Please always make sure your data and code are correct before posting your question.

Comment: For a more general information on how to craft your code samples for effective help, please read [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input data is effectively a dict but you are trying to use it as a list. There is no element named `0` (i.e. having a key which value is `0`) in your dict called `licences` (and since it is not a list, there is no first element at index `0` either).

What I understand from your question is that your `licences` dict will always contain a single key and that you want to get the `licence` number inside that key whatever the key name is. Please [edit](/posts/72583693/edit) your question to be more specific if my understanding is wrong.

One way to do this is:

```yaml
- name: Display licence ID
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.json.licences | dict2items | map(attribute='value.license') | first }}"
```

Explanation:

- the `dict2items` filter transforms your `result.json.licenses` dict

  ```json
  {
    "4216": {
      "license": "4512-5421-5134-7413"
    }
  }
  ```

  into a list of key/value dicts

  ```json
  [
    {
      "key": "4216",
      "value": {
        "license": "4512-5421-5134-7413"
      }
    }
  ]
  ```
- the `map(attribute='value.license`)` filter extracts the nested attribute from each element into a list

  ```json
  [
    "4512-5421-5134-7413"
  ]
  ```
- the `first` filter keeps only the first element from that list:

  ```json
  "4512-5421-5134-7413"
  ```

If you ever have several results and want to get a list of license number, just remove the `first` filter at the end. You can also build up on this example to get the key for the license if you need it one day.

Comment: Thanks ! This works well and helped me to understand why it was not working and will will also help me a lot in the future 

Answer (score 1):

- Create the complete path. Attribute '4216' is a string. It must be quoted. Put it into the brackets

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: result.json.licences['4216'].license
      vars:
        result:
          json:
            licences:
              '4216':
                license: 4512-5421-5134-7413
```

gives

```yaml
result.json.licences['4216'].license: 4512-5421-5134-7413
```

- If you don't know the number, or, in general, the name of the attribute, use *json_query*. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: result.json.licences|json_query('*.license')|first
```

- As a side note: If the attribute were a number 4216 you could have used it without quotes and brackets. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: result.json.licences.4216.license
      vars:
        result:
          json:
            licences:
              4216:
                license: 4512-5421-5134-7413
```

gives

```yaml
result.json.licences.4216.license: 4512-5421-5134-7413
```

- For details see [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables).

Comment: Thank you ! I do not know the attribute number. The json_query filter works well and I had a hard time to decide if I wanted to use json_query (the easiest) or dict2items. I chose dict2items in the end, because it will help me to remember to not confuse dictionaries with lists.